# Can't create repository:"App Name" 301 moved permanently

Tags: android, github

I had created a project of the same name earlier on GitHub, then later deleted it.
Now when I try to push my Android Studio project on to GitHub this error is shown

Answer (score 0):

connection android studio project before which you must be create repository on Github